# Django: How can I access celery flower page in production mode?

Tags: django, nginx, celery, flower

In development mode(local), it is really easy to access flower page (http://localhost:5555)

But in production mode, it is difficult to access flower page.

I'd like to access flower dashboard page with this url:
https://spacegraphy.choislaw.xyz/flower/ (Domain name : choislaw.xyz)

I refered http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reverse-proxy.html#reverse-proxy and this is what I did:

**nginx.conf**

```
  http {
      include       mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      sendfile        on;

      server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  spacegraphy.choislaw.xyz;

          client_max_body_size 4G;
          keepalive_timeout 5;

          return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
      }


      # HTTPS server
      server {
          listen       443 default_server ssl;
          server_name  spacegraphy.choislaw.xyz;

          client_max_body_size 4G;
          keepalive_timeout 5;

          ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/spacegraphy.choislaw.xyz/fullchain.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/spacegraphy.choislaw.xyz/privkey.pem;

          location / {
              proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4349;
              proxy_redirect off;
          }

          # Flower
          location /flower/ {
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
              proxy_http_version 1.1;

             proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/;
             proxy_redirect off;
         }
     }
 }
```

And I execute flower server:

```
$ celery --workdir=spacegraphy/  --app=spacegraphy.celery:app flower
```

And I access https://spacegraphy.choislaw.xyz/flower/, it shows like this:

[image]

And If I click any link,

[image]

Did I miss something? Do I separate flower server from application server?

Btw, Is it usual to run flower server on production server?

Comment: No settings for static files and location /tasks/

Comment: How can I deal with it?

Comment: Is it usual to run flower server on production server? 
For me, only enable it for maintenance purpose.

Comment: @Jinje How can I set settings file for static files for flower?

Comment: may refer to example here: [link](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf)

Comment: @Jinje static files might be located in my virtual environment's site-package/flower something. Is it the `/path/to/flower/static` ?

Comment: yes, path of the static folder of flower in the virtual environment package

Answer (score 11):

you need change flower nginx conf to:

```
location ~ ^/flower/? {
    rewrite ^/flower/?(.*)$ /$1 break;

    sub_filter '="/' '="/flower/';
    sub_filter_last_modified on;
    sub_filter_once off;

    # proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/flower.sock:/;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you'll need both previous solutions at the same time:

1. Run flower with **--url-prefix=flower** as @osmay88 mentioned
2. Configure Nginx location section in next manner:

   ```
   location ~ ^/flower/? {
       proxy_pass http://<IP>:<PORT>;
       rewrite ^/flower/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
   }
   ```

When in use without **url-prefix** but with **sub_filter** then this will cause *"Monitor"* page to be empty.

Comment: @Vladimir Sh. I'm trying to use flower in production too, however my flower doesn't have real time response. do you know how to configure the nginx for real time monitoring?

Comment: @luvwinnie
If I understand you correctly, there's a flag "celery flower --auto_refresh=True"

Answer (score 4):

you can run flower with --url-prefix=flower

Comment: Quick clarification: (I believe API might've changed) current docs indicate that this option should use an underscore (i.e. `flower --url_prefix=flower`) rather than a hyphen; source: https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#url-prefix

Answer (score 4):

[from doc](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#url-prefix)

```
$ flower --url_prefix=flower
```

nginx.conf

```
location /flower/ {
    rewrite ^/flower/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:5555;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```